# Google One-Tap-Login - "No credentials avaliable" error

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin, federated-identity, google-identity

I am trying to follow the simplest of examples of how to setup up Google's "
[One tap sign-up and automatic sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview)" in a web page. Just copy and pasting the code provided by google, I get an exception "No credentials available". Why? How to fix it?

This is my web page content ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<script src="https://smartlock.google.com/client"></script>

<script>

console.log( "window.location.origin=" + window.location.origin);

window.onGoogleYoloLoad = (googleyolo) => {
  console.log("Google one tap ready");
};

const retrievePromise = googleyolo.retrieve({
  supportedAuthMethods: [
    "https://accounts.google.com",
    "googleyolo://id-and-password"
  ],
  supportedIdTokenProviders: [
    {
      uri: "https://accounts.google.com",
      clientId: "xxxx-86peetl434op89ug41lg1vv8sjspfupp.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    }
  ]
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
Content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

The Authorized JavaScript origins has been correctly setup. I am confident of that. The URL for the above content is: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sbd-aws-sdk-delphi-22/index.html

Upon hitting the page (browser=Chrome), the resultant javascript console is ..

```
window.location.origin=https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
Google one tap ready
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
a {type: "noCredentialsAvailable", name: "OpenYoloError", message: 
"noCredentialsAvailable: No credential is available for the current user."}
message:
"noCredentialsAvailable: No credential is available for the current user."
```

Context: When I make this web page hit, I am logged into Google.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your issue solved ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is currently no user signed in.  The library has very little support for this, as a work around, when no Google Accounts are active and no credentials are available.  You can simply show the traditional Google Sign-In button and have the user click to proceed through the flow to activate their Google Account in the browser.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: I already have two account login in gmail still this error occur : `Credential are not available.` Is there Any other solution ?